# How to update PDF file in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to open an existing pdf file(with some content) in php and I want to add some more to it after getting information from forms on my webpage. Can I do that, if yes. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1st way

"TCPDF is a PHP class for generating PDF files on-the-fly without requiring external extensions. This library includes also a class to extract data from existing PDF documents and classes to generate 1D and 2D barcodes in various formats."

Take a look to this library: https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF

---

### 2nd way

Make a HTML template, edit the content you want, and convert the HTML to PHP with this: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf